# compute area under two curve

Tags: calculus

suppose  we  are  give task  to calculate area of figure,which is bounded by two curve
  $y=[x]$ and $y=(2-x^2)$, here  $[x]$  denotes  modulus,not  ceiling or  rounding  of x.

i use wolframalpha  to figure out  what kind of  location,intersection points  has this two figure,here is link of this
http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=abs%28x%29%3D2-x%5E2
i see that points of intersection  are $-1$ and $1$,also i know that  area under  two curve
$y=f_1(x)$ and  $y=f_2(x)$  and intersection points are $x_1$ and  $x_2$ is
  $$\int_{x_1}^{x_2}(f_2(x)-f_1(x))dx$$
but  i am confused if  i should take  $y=[x]$ directly or  consider  two interval $[-1..0]$ and $[0...1]$ and  use  $-x$ and $x$  for each interval? please give me some hint

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it separately, it is safer. Anyway, you only need to deal with the first quadrant part. By symmetry for the full area you double the result.

Because the curve $y=2-x^2$ is *above* the curve $y=x$ in the region of interest, the first quadrant part has area $\int_0^1((2-x^2)-x)\,dx$.

I would somewhat prefer to draw the vertical line from the point of intersection $(1,1)$ to the $x$-axis. Then the desired area is $\int_0^1 (2-x^2)\,dx -\int_0^1 x\,dx$. It feels more concrete: area under $y=2-x^2$, above $x$-axis, from $0$ to $1$, minus the area of the "hole."

Comment: so calculate area under   0..1 and the multiply by two yes?

Comment: Yes.${}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: i have calculated   area in first quadrant,get  $2/3$,so then i have multiplyed it by 2,so  get $4/3$

Comment: thanks very much for detailed answer

Comment: Really? I get a different number.

Comment: sorry which number?

Comment: aaaaaaaaaa,sorry i missed $x^2/2$  ,i missed 1/2

Comment: For the half area, integrate $2-x^2-x$. An antiderivative is $2x-x^3/3-x^2/2$. Plug in $1$, take away result of plugging in $0$. I get $7/6$. Then double to get $7/3$.

Comment: yes yes,sorry  i  have made mistake,did not  take care  that integral of x is x^2/2 and not  just x^2,i  have got it

Comment: thank you very much @ André Nicolas

Answer (score 1):

the absolute value of x is an even function (Y1=[x]) and (Y2=2-x^2) is  also a even function therefor y2-y1 is an even function by consequence.then the integral of y2-y1 between -1 and 1 is equal to the integral of Y2-Y1 enter 0 and 1 multiplied by two.
P.S:
In the interval [0 1] [x]=x.
area of figure = 2* 3.5/3=7/3.